# Change tkinter label color multiple times in same function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want to change the color of a label twice in the same function. I can't seem to get that to work.

The function is something like

```
    def do_work():
        print("in progress")
        label.config(font=("Calibri", 1, "bold"), fg="white")
        # run calculations
        print("complete")
        label.config(font=("Calibri", 1, "bold"), fg="green")
```

It seems like tkinter only allows one of these labels to work. It feels like I'm missing something fundamental about how tkinter works. Thank you.

Comment: Call `label.update_idletasks()` after `label.config(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code how you can change the color of the Label (after one second):

```py
import tkinter as tk


def on_button_click():
    label.config(font=("Calibri", 12, "bold"), fg="white")
    # after 1 second, it becomes green
    window.after(1000, lambda: label.config(font=("Calibri", 12, "bold"), fg="green"))


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tkinter Button Example")
button = tk.Button(window, text="Click Me", command=on_button_click)
label = tk.Label(window, text="Sample Text In Label")
label.config(font=("Calibri", 12, "bold"), fg="yellow")

button.pack(pady=10)
label.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Creates this application (clicking changes the first yellow text to white then after one second to green):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I feel like this is bringing me closer but I'm still having an issue. Let's see you add a sleep for 10 seconds in between the white and green light does your code still work? For me it only does the white and green after the sleep delay. I'm using the sleep as an example for where my long calculation happens.

Answer (score 1):

root.update() forces the config change. Otherwise tkinter waits until the next event loop iteration to update config. When you change the configuration of a Tkinter widget, the change does not happen immediately. Instead, the change is queued up and executed when the next event loop iteration occurs. This can be a problem if you need to make changes to the widget's configuration in response to user input.